# ajax style page reload with $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] and a switch statement

Tags: html, apache2, php4

I'm helping out a friend with her web page and I can't seem to make sense of the routing.
So this webpage was written years ago in php.

Essentially, there is stuff like this:

```
<li><a href="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?goto=start">Startseite</a></li>
<li><a href="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?goto=objekte">Objekte</a></li>
<li><a href="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?goto=nachfrage">Wir suchen</a></li>
<li><a href="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?goto=angebot">Sie bieten an</a></li>
<li><a href="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?goto=kontakt">Kontakt</a></li
```

Which works with a switch statement later on in the php page:

```
 <?
switch ($goto) {
    case "start":
        include("./startseite.inc.php");
    break;
    case "jobs":
        include("./jobs.inc.php");
    break;
    ....
    default:
        include("./startseite.inc.php");
    break;
?>
```

Now, when I run this locally, clicking on the links nothing gets reloaded, which makes me believe that it is something with the routing rules. I am no php programmer so I don't know if this is a valid technique.

Could someone explain to me / point me into the right direction of how the **goto** of the url: `www.site.com/index.php?goto=something`, gets resolved to the **$goto** var in the php code

P.s. On the first visit to the page i.e. index.php, the **startseite.inc.php** does get rendered fyi

Sorry if this is confusing, but the whole site is written in a very unstructured way.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `?goto=xyz` to a URL, you are adding the `goto` parameter (with the value `xyz`) to the HTTP GET request. PHP is capable of understanding these parameters. The only thing you have to do in order to access it's value is to read the corresponding value of PHP's built-in `$_GET` array like so:

```
$goto = $_GET['goto'];
```

PHP documentation on the `$_GET` array: [Reserved variables: GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. That line was not there, but the site used to work in production.. strange. Anyway, I added it and it works now! :)